# List of sf-object into one sf-object

Tags: r, sf, data-frame

that's a really simple question but I am kind of stuck with it. I have a list with multiple sf-objects and I want to put all sf-objects (dataframe) under each other and build one final sf-object. How could I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `do.call(rbind, things)` which does `rbind(thing[[1]], thing[[2]], thing[[3]], ..etc..)`?

Comment: exactly!! Thanks:) But what exactly dows "do.call". I read the documentation, but it's still a little unclear to me

Comment: It runs the functions given as the first argument as if passed the list in the second arguments as its argument. So `do.call(foo, list(a,b,c,d,e))` does the same as `foo(a,b,c,d,e)`. If you have a list of things you want to pass into a function as arguments, its the thing to use.